# Start Date and End Date Query not working

Tags: java, php, mysql, .net, sql

Following is the Requirement

If the search date range is 5/15/2013 to 5/21/2013, then events with the following event date ranges would be included or excluded:

```
1/01/2013 to 6/30/2013 include
2/15/2013 to 3/15/2013 exclude
5/01/2013 to 5/19/2013 include
5/01/2013 to 5/14/2013 exclude
5/15/2013 to 5/15/2013 include
5/21/2013 to 5/21/2013 include
5/17/2013 to 5/30/2013 include
5/16/2013 to 5/20/2013 include
5/22/2013 to 5/30/2013 exclude
*5/16/2013 to 00/00/0000 include
5/22/2013 to 00/00/0000 exclude*
```

Below is the query which I made but its not following above conditions

```
SELECT cm_id,cm_date_from,cm_date_to FROM Cat_Master
WHERE TRUE  AND ( "2013-05-15" BETWEEN cm_date_from AND cm_date_to OR "2013-05-21" BETWEEN cm_date_from AND cm_date_to
    OR "2013-05-15" >= cm_date_from AND "2013-05-21" <= cm_date_to   OR "2013-05-15" <= cm_date_from AND "2013-05-21" >= cm_date_to
    )
```

Please guide on above query
thanks

Comment: this question is simply related to mysql or sql.Why java,.net and php?

Comment: _"its not following above conditions"_ Can you point to conditions which are going wrong as per your query?

Answer (score 0):

> TO_DATE( string1, [ format_mask ], [ nls_language ] )

TO_DATE( '2013-05-15,  'yyyy-mm-dd' ).

For date comparisons use date variable.

P.S: I asumed you are using Oracle Db (Since you did not mention)

Comment: We are using MYSQL DB

Answer (score 0):

It seems you missed braces after 2nd and 3rd `OR` operators.
Try this:

```
SELECT cm_id,cm_date_from,cm_date_to
FROM Cat_Master
WHERE TRUE  AND ( 
  "2013-05-15" BETWEEN cm_date_from AND cm_date_to
  OR
  "2013-05-21" BETWEEN cm_date_from AND cm_date_to
  OR
  ( "2013-05-15" >= cm_date_from AND "2013-05-21" <= cm_date_to )
  OR
  ( "2013-05-15" <= cm_date_from AND "2013-05-21" >= cm_date_to )
    )
```

Comment: Hi, This query returns same result. I want result which can handle *5/16/2013 to 00/00/0000 include
5/22/2013 to 00/00/0000 exclude* , this result because in my db some  cm_date_from are 00/00/0000 default

Answer (score 0):

Use date types to compare dates.

```
  WHERE ( to_date('2013-05-15','YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN cm_date_from AND cm_date_to OR 
  to_date('2013-05-21','YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN cm_date_from AND cm_date_to
  OR to_date('2013-05-15','YYYY-MM-DD') >= cm_date_from AND to_date('2013-05-21','YYYY-MM-DD') <= 
  cm_date_to   OR to_date('2013-05-15','YYYY-MM-DD') <= cm_date_from AND 
to_date('2013-05-21','YYYY-MM-DD') >= cm_date_to  );
```